# ASP.NET ListView - how to group items?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a collection of objects, something like:

> name:Foo group: 1
>
> name:Fuu group: 1
>
> name:Bar group: 2
>
> name:Baz group: 2
>
> name:Bap group: 2
>
> name:Qux group: 3

I want to show these objects using a list view and they must be gouped, smth like:

> Foo, Fuu
>
> Bar, Baz, Bap
>
> Qux

I looked up GroupTemplate but the only grouping option is by number of items. Any ideea how to goup by a custom property?